# Temperature and other statistics from Radeon Open Source Drivers?

Tags: radeon, gpu

How can I see GPU % usage, temperature, fan speed, etc, with Radeon Open Source Drivers?

Comment: Please improve your question: Did you succeed with the proprietary drivers but fail with open source ones, did you check the usual suspects like sensors, xsensors, do you need a graphical or textual tool for display etc.

Comment: I use open source driver, dont know does proprietary drivers can do this? Any tool are OK. sensors or xsensors return only temperature. I need GPU% usage and GPU fan speed, how to get that?

Comment: Can AMD proprietary drivers get GPU% usage and GPU fan speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the usual approach:

- install the package `lm-sensors`
- run `sudo sensors-detect`, answer all the questions
- run `sensors` to see readings

For a GUI, you can use [sensors-unity](https://snapcraft.io/sensors-unity) from Snapcraft.

Comment: I know about this, and sensors only return GPU temerature. What about GPU% usage and GPU fan speed?

Comment: AFAIK not possible

Comment: Any other way to get this? Maybe AMD proprietary drivers can do this?

Comment: I did this and got the GPU temps coming up: http://i.imgur.com/vp5dBXR.png and adding this file: https://gist.github.com/hamstar/7092276 makes those `temp1`'s show up as `GPU x`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `radeontop` to get live statistics on your graphic card. It only works with r600 and newer.

```
sudo apt-get install radeontop
```

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92732/41104

Answer (score 0):

Yes the proprietary drivers can show temperature, gpu usage, fan, etc, information

```
aticonfig --odgc --odgt
```

(amdconfig = aticonfig, same file, different name)

I too am looking for the open source equivalent. You may be able to hack the aticonfig to work with the open source drivers.

Another tool you may try ([radeontop](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?72130-Announcing-radeontop-a-tool-for-viewing-%20the-GPU-usage)), requires libpciaccess-dev, libncurses-dev, pkg-config