# How to measure GPU usage?

Tags: software-recommendation, gpu

Using the `top` command in the terminal lists processes, sorted by their CPU usage (and you can change it to sort by another parameter)

Is there an equivalent for the GPU?

[This fellow is asking about RAM used by GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276039/how-can-i-find-the-memory-usage-on-my-gpu)

Comment: Deppending, if you are using a radeon you can use [radeontop](http://askubuntu.com/a/382160/169736), for nvidia there's another tool but I don't have the name at hand.

Comment: For nvidia it's the commandline tool `nvidia-smi`, except for the jetsons, where it is `tegrastats`.

Comment: For a nvidia gpu, you can use `nvidia-smi -l 5`, which will provide an update every 5 seconds. (Change this number to update at a different interval.)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

- For Nvidia GPUs there is a tool [nvidia-smi](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface) that can show memory
  usage, GPU utilization and temperature of GPU.
- For Intel GPU's you can use the [intel-gpu-tools](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/).
- AMD has two options

  1. fglrx (closed source drivers):

     ```
      aticonfig --odgc --odgt
     ```
  2. And for mesa (open source drivers), you can use [RadeonTop](https://github.com/clbr/radeontop)

     ```
     sudo apt install radeontop
     radeontop
     ```

---

<sup>Source:[GPU usage monitoring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/gpu-usage-monitoring-cuda)</sup>

Comment: Use `watch nvidia-smi` for real-time updates.

Comment: aticonfig won't work over SSH. Claims it needs an X server running to work (there is one running). However, RadeonTop (`sudo apt-get radeontop`) **does** work with the fglrx (needs root). Hurrah! Sadly RadeonTop doesn't provide any temperature readings.

Comment: aticonfig WILL work over SSH, but an X server with tcp enabled needs to be running. This can be done by configuring lightdm via `xserver-allow-tcp=true`. Searching around this site with these keywords should lead to the result.

Comment: Not sure why but `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` gave me real-time updates. `watch nvidia-smi` has a 2 sec update delay.

Comment: `sudo intel_gpu_top` should give you real time updates for intel gpus.

Comment: I like the radeontop.

Comment: You can use `nvidia-smi -l 1` for real-time updates. Source: [GPU usage monitoring (CUDA)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/gpu-usage-monitoring-cuda#:~:text=For%20linux%2C%20use%20nvidia%2Dsmi,refresh%20interval%20of%201%20second.)

Answer (score 51):

You can use [`gpustat`](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat), which is a  simple command-line script (wrapper for nvidia-smi) for querying and monitoring GPU status:

[image]

Comment: NOTE: Only for Nvidia

Comment: `pip install gpustat`

Comment: Works perfect with proprietary driver, thank you.

Answer (score 48):

For Intel:

1. Install intel-gpu-tools (its likely that they are installed already)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install intel-gpu-tools
   ```
2. Start the `top` like utility with

   ```
   sudo intel_gpu_top
   ```
3. Check your stats and then exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Thats what you get:

[image]

Thanks @Mitch! :)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem to be installed by default. I'm using Skylake GT2 (Intel HD Graphics 520).

Answer (score 37):

Nvidia: to continuously update the output of `nvidia-smi`, you can use `nvidia-smi --loop=1` (refresh interval of 1 second) or `nvidia-smi --loop-ms=1000` (refresh interval of 1000 milliseconds).

```
   -l SEC, --loop=SEC
       Continuously  report  query data at the specified interval, rather than
       the default of  just  once.   The  application  will  sleep  in-between
       queries.   Note  that on Linux ECC error or XID error events will print
       out during the sleep period if the -x flag was not specified.  Pressing
       Ctrl+C at any time will abort the loop, which will otherwise run indef‐
       initely.  If no argument is specified for the -l form a default  inter‐
       val of 5 seconds is used.

   -lms ms, --loop-ms=ms
       Same as -l,--loop but in milliseconds.
```

FYI:

- [How to log GPU load?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252594/16704)
- [GPU utilization is N/A when using nvidia-smi](https://askubuntu.com/q/701222/44876)

Answer (score 21):

You can use the  monitoring program [glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances) with its  [GPU monitoring](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/issues/170) plug-in:

- open source
- to install: `sudo apt-get install -y python-pip; sudo pip install glances`
- to launch: `sudo glances`

[image: Screenshot: close-up to glances's load details]

It also monitors the CPU, disk IO, disk space, network, and a few other things:

[image: Screenshot: glances running]

Comment: You also need to do `pip install nvidia-ml-py3`

Comment: It also works without `sudo` and when istalled for user only: `pip install --user glances[gpu]` and then run `glances`.

Answer (score 20):

I use the following command:

```
nvidia-smi -l 2
```

and it gives me updates every 2 seconds.

[image: looks like this]

Or :

```
watch -n0.1 "nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization -q useddedicatedgpumemory"
```

And on AMD, use:

```
aticonfig --odgc --odgt
```

[image]

Comment: `useddedicatedgpumemory` is that the tensorcores utilization?

Comment: If you installed your nvidia driver, it's probably already installed. Take a look with `whereis nvidia-smi` to find its location.

Answer (score 20):

## Conky

I like to use `conky` as a real-time monitor for both CPU and GPU. Installation is straightforward:

```
sudo apt install conky
```

### Intel i7-6700HQ iGPU HD 530

In this instance I've booted using the integrated GPU rather than the nVidia GTX 970M:

[image: Intel GPU.gif]

The `conky` code adapts depending on if booted with `prime-select intel` or `prime-select nvidia`:

### nVidia GPU GTX 970M

In this instance I've booted using the nVidia GTX 970M rather than the integrated GPU:

[image: nVidia GPU.GIF]

---

### Conky code

The conky code was recently modified to auto-sense the GPU. Now it doesn't have to be hand modified when rebooting to a different GPU:

```
#------------+
# Intel iGPU |
#------------+
${color orange}${hr 1}${if_existing /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_cur_freq_mhz}
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® Skylake GT2 HD 530 iGPU @${alignr}${color green}
${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_cur_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color}${goto 13}Min. Freq:${goto 120}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_min_freq_mhz)} MHz${color}${goto 210}Max. Freq:${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card0/gt_max_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color orange}${hr 1}${else}
#------------+
# Nvidia GPU |
#------------+
#${color orange}${hr 1}${if_match "${lsmod | grep nvidia_uvm}">""}
${color2}${voffset 5}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}@ ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.sm --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)}°C
${color1}${voffset 5}Ver: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1} P-State: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pstate --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}BIOS: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=vbios_version --format=csv,noheader)}
${color1}${voffset 5}GPU:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Ram:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Pwr:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Freq: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.mem --format=csv,noheader)}
${color orange}${hr 1}${endif}
```

Different versions of the full code listing can be found in these answers:

- [conky transparent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941701/conky-transparent/941705#941705)
- [Setting to High Performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604720/setting-to-high-performance/1047763#1047763)

Comment: Could you provide the steps to install conky and setup the theme to be like your Nvidia example please?

Comment: @Tak I've updated answer with installation instructions and existing links to code.

Answer (score 11):

I just found this command:

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv --loop=1
```

Here is a demo:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

No one mentioned the `nvtop` ? A nice tool similar to the `htop` we used to.
Installation is easy, simply do:

```
$ sudo apt install nvtop
or
$ snap install nvtop
```

The version from snap is usually a lot newer. The attractive feature is that it shows which process uses GPU by how much. A typical screenshot looks like the following:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my case `nvidia-smi` did not show the GPU load %, only the memory (guess my GTX 650 is too old).

What did work for me was the *NVIDIA X Server Settings* GUI app (shipped with the driver I believe). Navigate to the section named `GPU 0 - (Your Model)` - it shows the detailed status info of your GPU usage, updating every 2 seconds:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For AMD/ATi/Radeon cards on Linux Systems, CoreCtrl seems to do the job well.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one mentioned this command:

```
watch -n 1 nvidia-smi
```