# How do I profile (and possibly control) demands on my GPU?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

My GPU gets ungodly hot very quickly and I would like to see what is pushing it, how hard it is being pushed and then make an informed choice about upgrade, adding cooling or reconfiguring.

How do I profile my GPU's use and the applications making demands upon it?

I'm using: 12.04 (precise) [64-bit]

It's a GeForce GT that I want to profile.

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: this ques has already been answered
[http://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage][1]
hope this helps


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more generic because you don't give more info like if you run a mobile device and what drivers you are use.

First of all, check your module:

```
$ modinfo nvidia|grep -e Mobile
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
```

On notebooks you should have set `NVreg_Mobile=1`.

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf
options nvidia NVreg_Mobile=1 NVreg_EnableMSI=1
```

and rebuild you `initrd` with `update-initramfs -c -t -k all`.

The MSI setting is generally good for memory copy with a fast interface.

```
$ grep nvidia /proc/interrupts
45:  3969293       0   PCI-MSI-edge      nvidia
```

You should also use the `lm-sensors` package, which shows you the
system temperatures, voltages and fan speeds:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +43.0 C  (high = +80.0 C, crit = +85.0 C)
Core 0:         +40.0 C  (high = +80.0 C, crit = +85.0 C)
Core 1:         +42.0 C  (high = +80.0 C, crit = +85.0 C)

pkg-temp-0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0 C  

nct6775-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:          +0.98 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:            +1.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:           +3.33 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:          +3.33 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:            +1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:            +1.04 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:            +1.07 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:           +3.38 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:           +3.31 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
fan1:          1110 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 32)  ALARM
fan2:          1028 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 32)  ALARM
fan3:           562 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 32)  ALARM
fan4:             0 RPM  (div = 128)
SYSTIN:         +34.0 C  (high = +85.0 C, hyst = +75.0 C)  sensor = CPU diode
CPUTIN:         +35.0 C  (high = +80.0 C, hyst = +75.0 C)  sensor = CPU diode
PECI Agent 0:   +43.5 C  (high = +80.0 C, hyst = +75.0 C)  sensor = Intel PECI
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:  +49.0 C  
PECI Agent 1:    +0.0 C  (high = +80.0 C, hyst = +75.0 C)
cpu0_vid:      +0.000 V
intrusion0:    OK
```

If you think your `GPU-fan` is to slow, and the particular `fan` is listed,  then you can use the `fancontrol` tool to adjust it.

To read the temperature of you `GPU` use:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 nvidia-settings -q GPUCoreTemp -n -t
51
```

Comment: So how do I profile the applications making demands upon the GPU? (I know how to play with the fan and take a temperature reading). I really would like to know at what sort of level of floating point operations etc it was cooking to 105°C with.