# GPU utilization is N/A when using nvidia-smi

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I want to see the GPU usage of my graphic card. I use on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS x64, with two Nvidia GTX 690 cards. When I run `nvidia-smi -q` I get:

```
francky@francky-Aurora-R4:~$ nvidia-smi -q

==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Sun Nov 22 08:37:22 2015
Driver Version                      : 352.39

Attached GPUs                       : 2
GPU 0000:04:00.0
    Product Name                    : GeForce GTX 690
    Product Brand                   : GeForce
    Display Mode                    : N/A
    Display Active                  : N/A
    Persistence Mode                : Disabled
    Accounting Mode                 : N/A
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size     : N/A
    Driver Model
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Serial Number                   : N/A
    GPU UUID                        : GPU-e770f6fe-e8c6-466b-89e1-bc39d2a280bb
    Minor Number                    : 0
    VBIOS Version                   : 80.04.4C.00.0E
    MultiGPU Board                  : N/A
    Board ID                        : N/A
    Inforom Version
        Image Version               : N/A
        OEM Object                  : N/A
        ECC Object                  : N/A
        Power Management Object     : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                         : 0x04
        Device                      : 0x00
        Domain                      : 0x0000
        Device Id                   : 0x118810DE
        Bus Id                      : 0000:04:00.0
        Sub System Id               : 0x095B10DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                 : N/A
                Current             : N/A
            Link Width
                Max                 : N/A
                Current             : N/A
        Bridge Chip
            Type                    : N/A
            Firmware                : N/A
        Replays since reset         : 0
        Tx Throughput               : N/A
        Rx Throughput               : N/A
    Fan Speed                       : 43 %
    Performance State               : P0
    Clocks Throttle Reasons         : N/A
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                       : 2047 MiB
        Used                        : 237 MiB
        Free                        : 1810 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                       : N/A
        Used                        : N/A
        Free                        : N/A
    Compute Mode                    : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                         : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
        Encoder                     : N/A
        Decoder                     : N/A
    Ecc Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
            Double Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
        Aggregate
            Single Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
            Double Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC              : N/A
        Double Bit ECC              : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp            : 59 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp           : N/A
        GPU Slowdown Temp           : N/A
    Power Readings
        Power Management            : N/A
        Power Draw                  : N/A
        Power Limit                 : N/A
        Default Power Limit         : N/A
        Enforced Power Limit        : N/A
        Min Power Limit             : N/A
        Max Power Limit             : N/A
    Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        SM                          : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        SM                          : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                  : N/A
        Auto Boost Default          : N/A
    Processes                       : N/A

GPU 0000:05:00.0
    Product Name                    : GeForce GTX 690
    Product Brand                   : GeForce
    Display Mode                    : N/A
    Display Active                  : N/A
    Persistence Mode                : Disabled
    Accounting Mode                 : N/A
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size     : N/A
    Driver Model
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Serial Number                   : N/A
    GPU UUID                        : GPU-7a0d0c06-7285-a503-c130-32de1ce1d24d
    Minor Number                    : 1
    VBIOS Version                   : 80.04.4C.00.0F
    MultiGPU Board                  : N/A
    Board ID                        : N/A
    Inforom Version
        Image Version               : N/A
        OEM Object                  : N/A
        ECC Object                  : N/A
        Power Management Object     : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                         : 0x05
        Device                      : 0x00
        Domain                      : 0x0000
        Device Id                   : 0x118810DE
        Bus Id                      : 0000:05:00.0
        Sub System Id               : 0x095B10DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                 : N/A
                Current             : N/A
            Link Width
                Max                 : N/A
                Current             : N/A
        Bridge Chip
            Type                    : N/A
            Firmware                : N/A
        Replays since reset         : 0
        Tx Throughput               : N/A
        Rx Throughput               : N/A
    Fan Speed                       : 30 %
    Performance State               : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons         : N/A
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                       : 2047 MiB
        Used                        : 244 MiB
        Free                        : 1803 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                       : N/A
        Used                        : N/A
        Free                        : N/A
    Compute Mode                    : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                         : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
        Encoder                     : N/A
        Decoder                     : N/A
    Ecc Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
            Double Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
        Aggregate
            Single Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
            Double Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC              : N/A
        Double Bit ECC              : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp            : 33 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp           : N/A
        GPU Slowdown Temp           : N/A
    Power Readings
        Power Management            : N/A
        Power Draw                  : N/A
        Power Limit                 : N/A
        Default Power Limit         : N/A
        Enforced Power Limit        : N/A
        Min Power Limit             : N/A
        Max Power Limit             : N/A
    Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        SM                          : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        SM                          : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                  : N/A
        Auto Boost Default          : N/A
    Processes                       : N/A
```

Why is the GPU utilization N/A, and how to fix or circumvent the issue? I just want the GPU utilization and and I am fine using another tool for that.

Normally, the GPU utilization would be displayed as follows:

```
nvidia-smi -q

==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Fri Dec 11 11:40:25 2015
Driver Version                      : 352.39

Attached GPUs                       : 3
GPU 0000:01:00.0
    Product Name                    : GeForce GTX TITAN X
    Product Brand                   : GeForce
    Display Mode                    : Disabled
    Display Active                  : Disabled
    Persistence Mode                : Disabled
    Accounting Mode                 : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size     : 1920
    Driver Model
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Serial Number                   : 0420115017035
    GPU UUID                        : GPU-4ef51df0-f0bb-0da5-9418-ef1060190073
    Minor Number                    : 0
    VBIOS Version                   : 84.00.1F.00.90
    MultiGPU Board                  : No
    Board ID                        : 0x100
    Inforom Version
        Image Version               : G001.0000.01.03
        OEM Object                  : 1.1
        ECC Object                  : N/A
        Power Management Object     : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                         : 0x01
        Device                      : 0x00
        Domain                      : 0x0000
        Device Id                   : 0x17C210DE
        Bus Id                      : 0000:01:00.0
        Sub System Id               : 0x29923842
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                 : 3
                Current             : 3
            Link Width
                Max                 : 16x
                Current             : 8x
        Bridge Chip
            Type                    : N/A
            Firmware                : N/A
        Replays since reset         : 0
        Tx Throughput               : 388000 KB/s
        Rx Throughput               : 80000 KB/s
    Fan Speed                       : 46 %
    Performance State               : P2
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                        : Not Active
        Applications Clocks Setting : Not Active
        SW Power Cap                : Not Active
        HW Slowdown                 : Not Active
        Unknown                     : Active
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                       : 12287 MiB
        Used                        : 7490 MiB
        Free                        : 4797 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                       : 256 MiB
        Used                        : 4 MiB
        Free                        : 252 MiB
    Compute Mode                    : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                         : 71 %
        Memory                      : 37 %
        Encoder                     : 0 %
        Decoder                     : 0 %
    Ecc Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
            Double Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
        Aggregate
            Single Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
            Double Bit
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC              : N/A
        Double Bit ECC              : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp            : 81 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp           : 97 C
        GPU Slowdown Temp           : 92 C
    Power Readings
        Power Management            : Supported
        Power Draw                  : 139.90 W
        Power Limit                 : 250.00 W
        Default Power Limit         : 250.00 W
        Enforced Power Limit        : 250.00 W
        Min Power Limit             : 150.00 W
        Max Power Limit             : 275.00 W
    Clocks
        Graphics                    : 1341 MHz
        SM                          : 1341 MHz
        Memory                      : 3304 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : 1126 MHz
        Memory                      : 3505 MHz
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : 1126 MHz
        Memory                      : 3505 MHz
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                    : 1518 MHz
        SM                          : 1518 MHz
        Memory                      : 3505 MHz
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                  : On
        Auto Boost Default          : On
    Processes
        Process ID                  : 30463
            Type                    : C
            Name                    : /home/francky/torch/install/bin/luajit
            Used GPU Memory         : 7465 MiB
```

Comment: Same here with a pair of 780Ti. The best I could get was monitoring performance states with            nvidia-smi -l 1 --query --display=PERFORMANCE --filename=gpu_utillization.log

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190856/alternative-to-nvidia-smi-for-measuring-gpu-utilization/22901574) thread offers multiple alternatives. I had the same issue and in my case *nvidia-settings* enabled me to gain the gpu utilization information I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Nvidia broke profiling support for geforce cards since driver version 270.26. Only Quadro cards currently support gpu usage monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

You were using a four year old version of `nvidia-smi`. The new version supports my GTX 970M and will no doubt support your GTX 960 from the same family:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Apr 30 17:07:43 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   59C    P0    25W /  N/A |   1287MiB /  3016MiB |     37%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1300      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          1050MiB |
|    0      2482      G   compiz                                       233MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

A snippet from `nvidia-smi -q` output:

```
$ nvidia-smi -q

==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Tue Apr 30 17:08:30 2019
Driver Version                      : 384.130

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Product Name                    : GeForce GTX 970M
    Product Brand                   : GeForce
    Display Mode                    : Enabled
    Display Active                  : Enabled
    Persistence Mode                : Disabled
    Accounting Mode                 : Disabled

(.... SNIP ....)

    Utilization
        Gpu                         : 36 %
        Memory                      : 11 %
        Encoder                     : 0 %
        Decoder                     : 0 %

(.... SNIP ....)
```

As you can see where the GPU once said `N/A` it now says `36 %` (in my case and point in time).