# How do I stress test CPU and RAM (at the same time)?

Tags: software-recommendation, stress-testing

I've searched the net and came across the Ubuntu wiki saying

```
stress-ng --matrix 0
```

is supposed the best. But there are dedicated stressors for CPU and RAM (looking at man).

Any ideas which one is the best to use? Thank you

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can install `stress` with:

```
sudo apt install stress
```

Then call it with:

```
stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 4 --vm-bytes 1024M --timeout 10s
```

On my conky display notice how:

- In the top section CPU utilization spikes from 3% to 100%
- In the middle the temperature spikes from 60C to 80C
- At the bottom memory spikes from normal 2.75 GiB to 6.25 GiB

[image: stress test.gif]

Type `stress --help` for a full list of options.

---

A commentator requested posting the entire conky script which I did here: [conky transparent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941701/conky-transparent/941705#941705)

Comment: `stress` is not installed by default, at least not on 16.04.

Comment: @muru Once again you are right: `$ apt list stress
Listing... Done
stress/xenial,now 1.0.4-1 amd64 [installed]` I just don't remember installing it I guess. I'll revise the answer.

Comment: @mrjayviper It is called `conky` it's a light weight system monitor that is highly configurable and very popular in Linux world. You can google `conky` for more information. You can also search here in ***Ask Ubuntu*** and in Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix can you please share the conky theme? thank you

Comment: @mrjayviper Had to search a bit to find the old post but here it is: [Ubuntu Forums share your .conkyrc](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865&page=2327&p=13629343#post13629343) There are many other .conkyrc themes in the forum better than my own.

Comment: @mrjayviper I posted the script for another commentor which you'll find easier to access here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/941701/conky-transparent/941705#941705

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in order to install stress and /or conky as outlined in your answer and comments you must first [enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)