# How do I successfully configure pi-fancontrol on a Pi 4?

Tags: snap, raspberrypi, 20.10

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Adafruit's Official Case fan, and am running Ubuntu 20.10. I have installed the `pi-fancontrol` snap, but I can't get it configured using the instructions at https://snapcraft.io/install/pi-fancontrol/ubuntu.

```
$ sudo snap install pi-fancontrol
pi-fancontrol 0.1 from Oliver Grawert (ogra) installed
$ sudo snap connect pi-fancontrol:gpio pi:bcm-gpio-14
error: snap "pi" has no slot named "bcm-gpio-14"
```

`snap list` doesn't show that the `pi` snap is installed, so maybe that's the problem. There are instructions for that at https://snapcraft.io/install/pi/ubuntu.

```
$ sudo snap install pi --beta
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "pi" (11) (cannot install gadget snap on classic if not requested by the model)
```

Googling that error message does not turn up any useful results. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pi-fancontrol` snap is currently broken for Ubuntu Desktop.

Manually overriding worked for me.

```
sudo nano ../../boot/firmware/config.txt
```

To set the threshold at 80 degrees Celsius, add the following line in it:

```
dtoverlay=gpio-fan,gpiopin=14,temp=80000
```

Save the file by pressing `Ctrl` + `X`, and press `Y`, and press `Enter`.

Reboot the system now, it is done.

Comment: For temp=80000, what threshold does it represent? My fan is running at <50°C, and I would like it to automatically shut off at that point, starting again around 60°.

Comment: I'm also curious to know - If I'm using the default pins 04 and 06 (5v and ground) and want to continue using them, what would the GPIO value equal?

Comment: `temp=60000` is to turn the fan on at 60°C. And from what I understand it will turn off again at 50°C.

Comment: @mustafa-tufan Where's your other wire? This kind of works for me too but compared to when I connected my fan to 3.3V and ground, the fan lights are more dim and flickering. Doesn't feel right.

Comment: Works great.  Thanks.  This answer is helpful for testing: https://askubuntu.com/questions/948854/how-do-i-stress-test-cpu-and-ram-at-the-same-time