# Cannot access to the internet via wireless by QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

I cannot use wifi on Dell Latitude 3470 on Ubuntu 14.04.
By far, I even cannot scan out the possible wifi list but other devices can scan out.

```
zelongg@zelongg:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for zelongg: 
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 32
       serial: 28:56:5a:54:4a:93
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.2.0-27-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:282 memory:d5000000-d51fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: 98:40:bb:25:5f:55
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=10.7.6.138 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:127 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d5204000-d5204fff memory:d5200000-d5203fff
zelongg@zelongg:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

zelongg@zelongg:~$ rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
zelongg@zelongg:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0310]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
zelongg@zelongg:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Updated:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323812

```
zelongg@zelongg:~$ cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
zelongg@zelongg:/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0$ ls -la
total 816
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2月 24 10:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 10月 9 17:03 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8124 3月 21 2016 board.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 733784 3月 21 2016 firmware-4.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 79689 3月 21 2016 notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt
zelongg@zelongg:/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0$ sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
--2018-02-26 17:20:08-- https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.113, 192.30.253.112
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.113|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘board-2.bin’

  [ <=> ] 31,113 60.0KB/s in 0.5s

2018-02-26 17:20:10 (60.0 KB/s) - ‘board-2.bin’ saved [31113]

zelongg@zelongg:/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0$ sudo mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin.bak
zelongg@zelongg:/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0$ sudo mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
zelongg@zelongg:/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0$

zelongg@zelongg:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for zelongg:
  *-network
  description: Network controller
  product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
  version: 32
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
  configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
  resources: irq:281 memory:d5000000-d51fffff
  *-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
  logical name: eth0
  version: 0c
  serial: 98:40:bb:25:5f:55
  size: 1Gbit/s
  capacity: 1Gbit/s
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=10.7.6.138 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
  resources: irq:127 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d5204000-d5204fff memory:d5200000-d5203fff
```

but there is no Enable Wi-Fi option in the drop down menu

So I reverted it. It has Enable Wi-Fi option in the drop down menu now.

```
zelongg@zelongg:~$ sudo mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
[sudo] password for zelongg:
zelongg@zelongg:~$ sudo mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin.bak /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin

zelongg@zelongg:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for zelongg:
  *-network DISABLED
  description: Wireless interface
  product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
  logical name: wlan0
  version: 32
  serial: 28:56:5a:54:4a:93
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.2.0-42-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
  resources: irq:282 memory:d5000000-d51fffff
  *-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
  logical name: eth0
  version: 0c
  serial: 98:40:bb:25:5f:55
  size: 1Gbit/s
  capacity: 1Gbit/s
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=10.7.6.138 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
  resources: irq:127 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d5204000-d5204fff memory:d5200000-d5203fff

zelongg@zelongg:~$ iwconfig
^C
zelongg@zelongg:~$ ifconfig
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 98:40:bb:25:5f:55
  inet addr:10.7.6.138 Bcast:10.7.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0
  inet6 addr: fe80::9a40:bbff:fe25:5f55/64 Scope:Link
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
  RX packets:18755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
  RX bytes:1466748 (1.4 MB) TX bytes:89250 (89.2 KB)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
  inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
  RX packets:479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
  RX bytes:80313 (80.3 KB) TX bytes:80313 (80.3 KB)
```

Updated 2:

```
zelongg@zelongg:~$ dmesg | grep ath10k
[ 1.593418] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[ 1.600708] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[ 1.820905] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[ 1.823833] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-pci-168c:003e:1028:0310.bin failed with error -2
[ 1.823839] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2
[ 1.827398] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[ 1.827403] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[ 4.013111] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff, 168c:003e:1028:0310 fallback) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 htt 3.26 wmi 4 cal otp max_sta 32
[ 4.013118] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
```

Update 3:
Kernel Version:

```
zelongg@zelongg:~$ uname -r
4.2.0-42-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 there will be too many output printed. Anything more specific using grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrade the Ubuntu version from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, everything works well.

Answer (score 1):

### Feb 26/2018 Update:

There appears to be an [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343) with 14.04 and ath10k driver. This has not been fixed yet in the main repositories. **First try chili555's suggestion.** If that doesn't work then review the bug report and try the fix there. Briefly bug work around fix is to:

```
sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/

sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/* 2> /dev/null

sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin?raw=true

sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin?raw=true

sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1?raw=true
```

You will see comments from me in the bug report between #88 and #93. The developer points out being on HWE (Hardware Enablement Stack) could have automatically fixed the problem within Ubuntu 16.04. I'm not sure about Ubuntu 14.04 though.

From my point of view the problem with HWE is it automatically updates kernels for Metldown and Spectre that caused problems for many people: [Is it safe to let "Sotware Updater" install all suggested updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007795/is-it-safe-to-let-sotware-updater-install-all-suggested-updates/1007808#1007808)

Comment #95 in the bug report mentions:

> just found the latest firmware is already in xenial-proposed
>   linux-firmware (1.157.15) xenial; urgency=medium

---

### Original Post:

The command output of: `sudo lshw -class network` shows your network Wifi card as "disabled". In the animation below the same model of card is initially shown as disabled. Then from the system tray menu the Network icon is clicked. From the drop down menu the "Enable WiFi" option is clicked on. Then `lshw` is run again and the Wifi card is no longer disabled:

[image: enable wifi.gif]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I have already enabled Wi-Fi, the drop down menu the "Enable WiFi" option is clicked on. 
So any further idea?

Comment: @FrancisBacon Chili's answer below to upgrade the firmware is spot on. It was recently changed to fix drop outs every 20 minutes. Also what is your kernel version? `uname -r`

Comment: The kernel version is 4.2.0-42-generic

Comment: @FrancisBacon The bug report mentions kernel version must be >= 4.5 for patches to work.

Comment: "The developer points out being on HWE (Hardware Enablement Stack) could have automatically fixed the problem within Ubuntu 16.04. "
Thanks for this, I updated the Ubuntu version, and it works well.

Comment: @FrancisBacon That's good to hear! Can I ask what your kernel version is now?

Comment: My current kernel version is 4.4.0-116-generic. It seems that it does not have to be >=4.5 :) Thanks for your reply, I do not have enough reputation, sorry for being unable to upvote your answer.

Comment: BTW, how can you create the gif in your answer?

Comment: And how to show the right panel like yours, I would like to have one too.

Comment: @FrancisBacon To create the `.gif` I used [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek)

Comment: @FrancisBacon The right panel is [Conky](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865). This link has 3,000 posts. Here is how mine is setup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/941701/conky-transparent/941705#941705

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try upgrading the firmware. From the terminal:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: I tried to install /home/zelongg/linux-firmware_1.157_all.deb, after reboot, nothing changes unfortunately.

Comment: I suggested the newer 1.169.2 version. Please try again.

Comment: thanks, I tried the newer 1.169.2, but it seems that the installation goes wrong. Now I fixed this problem, thanks for your answer. I do not have enough reputation, sorry for not being able to upvote your answer.