# CPU Frequency is allways the lowest possible (and high CPU usage)

Tags: 16.04, performance, cpu

Recently, I've noticed that my PC is very slow (even youtube videos aren't fluent).

I have **acer aspire nitro 5** and my battery is probably dead.

I thought that it's throttling because of high CPU temperatures but it isn't:

**sensors**

[image]

I can see that CPU frequency is about 800.000 MHZ which is the lowest possible.

**lscpu**

[image]

And as you can see the usage is very high (I started Intellij Idea)

[[image]

I tried to manually set CPU frequency to max:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -f `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`
```

but it returns error:

> Error setting new values. Common errors:
>   - Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?)
>   - Is the governor you requested available and modprobed?
>   - Trying to set an invalid policy?
>   - Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available,    for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a
>   specific frequency    or because the userspace governor isn't loaded?

Do you know what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dead battery

A battery below 5% charge is a critical issue and all sorts of exceptions will be implemented by the software. This might include limiting speed until battery goes above 10-30% charge. Which in your case would never happen. You could probably pick up a used / refurbished battery fairly cheaply on eBay or Amazon.

---

### Set to Performance governor in `cpufrequtils`

From this **[Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/936488/307523)**, follow these steps:

Edit the following file (if it doesn't exist, create it):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/cpufrequtils
```

And add the following line to it:

```
GOVERNOR="performance"
```

Save and exit.

For changes to immediately take effect without rebooting, run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils restart
```

Then you can run `cpufreq-info` to see informations about your cpu frequency, governor and more:

```
$ cpufreq-info
current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.90 GHz.
          The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
          within this range.
```

---

From another answer [Setting to High Performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604720/setting-to-high-performance/1047763#1047763): you can see CPU frequency differences between **Powersave** and **Performance** governors:

### Performance Mode

In **performance** mode you will then notice CPU% utilization drops by about 5% but also notice speed will increase from about 1000 MHz to 3000 MHz and temperatures will spike by ~10 degree, depending on your processor:

[image: CPU Performance mode.gif]

---

### Powersave mode

[image: CPU powersave.gif]

Switching back to **powersave** mode CPU% utilization has spiked by 5%, but CPU frequency has dropped by 1500 MHz and temperature has decreased by about 10 degrees. Overall **powersave** mode is the best for most configurations.

Comment: Thanks, but the frequency is still the same even after performing steps you mentioned above.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik Hmm... I'll have to research this one more. In the meantime can you click on the second link **Setting to High Performance** and try the command line steps outlined there?

Comment: I've read that sometimes this is caused by battery for some reason, since my battery is dead, I will try to unplug it.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik Yes a battery below 5% charge is a critical issue and all sorts of exceptions will be implemented by the software. This might include limiting speed until battery goes above 10-30% charge. Which in your case would never happen. You could probably pick up a used / refurbished battery fairly cheaply on eBay or Amazon.

Comment: Unplugging battery have helped. Now the frequency is variable, thanks for yout help!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, what app is that in the screenshots?

Comment: @Garrett It's Conky, "A light weight system monitor". Here is an older copy of the script I found: https://askubuntu.com/questions/941701/conky-transparent/941705#941705 Everyone's conky script is different: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865