# Want a fully functional 18.04 hardware monitor

Tags: hardware, monitoring, system-monitor

Having trouble finding a hardware monitor. I tried GNOME's [system-monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/), but it doesn't show most of the possible info; I only get the CPU temp. My system has the [MSI Gaming Edge AC](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-Z390-GAMING-EDGE-AC) with a [Sapphire Radeon RX Vega 64 Nitro+](https://www.sapphiretech.com/en/consumer/nitro-rx-vega64-8g-hbm2).

Comment: Check out `glances` : https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `conky`:

```
 sudo apt install conky
```

Conky is a light weight system monitor that let's you pick and choose system information and your own information and place it on the same window you can move anywhere:

[image: Conky July 19 2019.gif]

My design is about four years out-of-date and not nearly as fancy as "modern" `conky` scripts.

---

### Ubuntu 18.04

It's come to my attention some people (or everyone?) is having problems with conky under version 18.04. In which case I found this blog:

- [How to install Conky and Conky Manager](https://www.fosslicious.com/2018/05/how-to-install-conky-and-conky-manager.html)

I had upgraded my 16.04 to 18.04 last year and don't recall any problems with conky. That said I rarely use 18.04 and prefer the stability and comfort of 16.04.6 LTS.

Comment: Can you please share this? After isntalling Conky it doesn't look like this. How do I make it look like this?

Comment: @NeonWarge Everyone can have their own conky script tailored to their system and personal preferences. Here's the one I used above: https://askubuntu.com/a/941705/307523

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend the [Open Source HW Monitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/)?  On Linux systems the Open Hardware Monitor requires [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/) with [WinForms](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/).