# How to analyze video card RAM and GPU load?

Tags: video, performance, ram, top, free

I would like to analyze my video card performance (RAM, load, etc) the way that top, free and lscpu does for my main hardware.

Is there an app to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is actually a duplicate of [How to measure GPU usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage)

Here are all the suggestions in one simple list:

- Nvidia GPUs: `nvidia-smi --loop-ms=1000`
- Nvidia GPUs: [ntop](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop)
- Intel GPUs: `intel-gpu-tools`
- AMD GPUs: fglrx (closed source drivers): aticonfig --odgc --odgt
- AMD GPUs: mesa (open source drivers): [RadeonTop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/radeontop)
- GPUstat: [gpustat](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat)
- Conky: `sudo apt install conky` ( I can't get this to work )
- Glances: [glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances)

Answer (score 1):

I found two tools, so decide which works best for your needs:

1. glmark2:

   - Installation:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install glmark2
     # usage
     glmark2
     ```
2. glx-gears:

   - installation:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
     # usage
     glxgears
     ```

Then in case your looking for something more robust, then try the tools from Unigine Benchmark Products: link => https://benchmark.unigine.com/heaven

Comment: these just seem to do benchmarking by forcing 3d rendering... I don't see any actual info on the card.... gpu and ram usage to be specific

Comment: I don't use these tools myself but perhaps the last edit in my post would do better.

Comment: downloading heaven now... looks like it might be the one, I will let you know