# Is there a way measure nvidia GPU usage with better accuracy?

Tags: nvidia, performance, gpu

I am trying to measure nvidia GPU utilization on Ubuntu, as explained in [How to measure GPU usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387594/how-to-measure-gpu-usage) with results as accurate as possible. I set the nvidia-smi loop interval to 5 ms, and indeed I am getting about 200 samples a second. Unfortunately it seems that the nvidia-smi can only produce results in resolution of ~170ms (so for each such interval I'm getting about 35 samples which are exactly the same).

Is there any way to increase the nvidia-smi sampling resolution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if using `nvidia-smi` or any bindings (Python/Perl/Go) with NVML. The highest resolution is recorded in [NVML API Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/structnvmlUtilization__t.html#structnvmlUtilization__t) that,

> Utilization information for a device. Each sample period may be between 1 second and 1/6 second, depending on the product being queried.

Therefore, your observation that "resolution of ~170ms" is quite precise. For further accuracy, it is recommended to use [DCGM](https://developer.nvidia.com/dcgm) (only suitable for certain series of GPUs).